# How to recover Apache reverse proxy fast after proxy error?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have benn running Apache2 frontends as reverse proxy configurations for years now.

What I was not able to change is the behaviour after a backend server goes down for a short time (i.e. restart)

Apache will continue to deliver the proxy error page for a long time, before it re-checks if the backend has come back. I need to manually restart each time and I can understand the users are annyoed.

How can I tell apache to not remember the "broken" proxy backend, but retry each time?

If that is not possible, how can I configure the time apache "caches the error" to be very short, lets say 10 seconds.

I am talking about very simple standard reverse proxy configurations more or less like this:

```
ProxyPass        /site http://10.1.1.8/backend
ProxyPassReverse /site http://10.1.1.8/backend
```

Comment: From time to time I search for a solution but maybe looking in the wrong directions or not using the correct keywords? I find a lot about timeout of the request, but I need a solution for the timeout of the error caching

Answer (score 1):

I found this by chance - because Serverfault showed to me all the reverse proxy questions in the sidebar:

https://serverfault.com/a/142961/129177

The solution seems to be:

```
ProxyPass        /site http://10.1.1.8/backend retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /site http://10.1.1.8/backend
```

Comment: But I am open for better answers or different methods, but this is so simple, so I would probably go with this solution.